# powershell.exe start-process -Verbオプション使用時の"\"について

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

よろしくお願いいたします。
Windows10のコマンドプロンプトでPowershellを利用し管理者権限でコマンドを実行しようとしています。
以下のａ，ｂ，ｃの3つを試すと"RunAs"での起動が思うようにできません。
解決方法がわかる方はいらっしゃいますか？

(a)正常に実行できる。引数も正しく渡される。

```
powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'TestEnv.cmd' -ArgumentList '\"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -Verb Open
```

(b)ＵＡＣ確認後、起動しない。

```
powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'TestEnv.cmd' -ArgumentList '\"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -Verb RunAs
```

(c)起動できますが引数の"ダブルクォーテーションが反映されず"B C"は別々に認識されてしまう。

```
powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'TestEnv.cmd' -ArgumentList '"a" "B C" "d"' -Verb RunAs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

拡張子`.cmd`はOSが直接実行できず、`cmd.exe`が解釈して実行します。PowerShell及びその下位レイヤーが`cmd.exe`を起動する際に渡す引数と`cmd.exe`が渡された引数を解釈方法に齟齬があるため、期待する引数を確実に渡すことができないようです。

```
powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/C "path\to\TestEnv.cmd" \"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -Verb open
powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/C "path\to\TestEnv.cmd" \"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -Verb runas
```

のように`.cmd`を起動するのではなく、`cmd.exe`を起動することにより`-Verb`による差異を受けないようにするといいでしょう。

---

調査したこと：

> ```
> powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'TestEnv.cmd' -ArgumentList '\"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -Verb Open
> ```

この方法で起動されるプロセス及び引数は

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\sayuri\TestEnv.cmd" "a" "B C" "d" "
```

であり、`-FilePath`が`""`で括られた上で更に`-FilePath`と`-ArgumentList`を含めた全体が`""`で括られている。
`cmd.exe`は外側の`"`を削除してから解釈するため期待通り`"C:\Users\sayuri\TestEnv.cmd"`が実行される。

> ```
> powershell.exe start-process -FilePath 'TestEnv.cmd' -ArgumentList '\"a\" \"B C\" \"d\"' -Verb RunAs
> ```

この方法で起動されるプロセス及び引数は

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe" /C "C:\Users\sayuri\TestEnv.cmd" "a" "B C" "d"
```

であり、`-FilePath`が`""`で括られている。
`cmd.exe`は外側の`"`を削除してから解釈する。その際、`""`の対を考慮して空白までの文字列として
`C:\Users\sayuri\TestEnv.cmd" "a" "B`という実行ファイルを探しに行くため

```
'C:\Users\sayuri\TestEnv.cmd" "a" "B' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

というエラーが発生している。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。

Comment: 途中でコメントが保存されていました。  改めてご回答いただき、また非常にわかりやすくご説明いただきありがとうございます。 
 内部で起こっている事象は理解できたのですがなぜ別のオプション同士が干渉してしまうのか謎ですね。  たとえばオプションの使い方やエスケープシーケンスの使い方で解決できるならと考えていたのですが回避策はありますが、解決には至らないようですね。  実はWSHのShellExecute関数にも同じような現象が確認されており、現状、バグらしいと結論づけてマイクロソフトに報告をいたしました。  管理者権限で実行と引数を付けて実行を分けることで回避できることがわかっているので、今はそれで回避しようと思います。  ありがとうございました。